# Safari Body Tag CSS file not referenced

Tags: css, html, safari, stylesheet

I download the CSS file after index page launched. that css file placed in the body tag.  But the corresponding CSS not applied to the controls.  It works in IE and CHROME perfectly. Safari only the problem

Comment: Not enough info for anyone to help with this. Provide a link or demo.

Comment: With In Body Tag Some CSS files are there, that files not referenced in Safari